# I'm trying to get a cookie's value, but it has a . infront and it doesn't set it's value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a cookie called ".ROBLOSECURITY".
When I try get it's value it pops up as "null".

Is there a way to get it's value?

I'm using Javascript and JSON.

The code I used is

document.cookie=".ROBLOSECURITY"
When I run that it just makes a new cookie inside the cookies, which is not what I want.
How can be there 2 of the same cookies.
When I delete one of them the other get's deleted

Comment: What's your code

Comment: I'm using javascript

Comment: No, what is the code you are having trouble with? You need to click [edit] and show us some actual JavaScript code, otherwise we'll just be guessing what you're doing, and that's a waste of our time and yours.

Comment: I edited it now, if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) I believe that, using the way you are using it, you have to pass the string as a "key=value" string, this way you can identify it:

```
document.cookie = "youCookie=.ROBLOSECURITY";
```

And for getiting a cookie value, you have to build a logic to get the exact value you are searching, since cookies are stored as a single string:

```
const cookieValue = document.cookie
.split('; ')
.find(row => row.startsWith('youCookie='))
.split('=')[1];
```

Obs1: Since you are using javascript, there is a npm package that makes it easier to get set and delete a cookie. You can use the [doc-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/doc-cookies) package for example:

```
import docCookies from 'doc-cookies';

docCookies.setItem('youCookie', '.ROBLOSECURITY');

const cookieValue = docCookies.getItem('youCookie');
```

Obs2: You can also use the Application tab on devltools on your browser to check the cookies you have set.

Comment: My problem is that the cookie's name is .ROBLOSECURITY, and I'm trying to get all of it's value it has through a discord webhook.

Comment: But are you able to see it on the devtools on the Application>Cookies tab? Is it there where you see copies of it?

Comment: No I cannot see it